# Visual Studio Code: Debug JavaScript with Firefox ESR

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a launch.json file for firefox, edge and chrome. However I also need to test the application with a Firefox ESR. Is there a way to do this?

I would need something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
          "type": "firefox",
          "request": "launch",
          "reAttach": false,
          "name": "Launch Firefox against localhost",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
          "type": "firefox-esr",
          "request": "launch",
          "reAttach": false,
          "name": "Launch Firefox ESR against localhost",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try the official Debugger for Firefox extension (`firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug`)?

Comment: @Sv443 yes, that's how I debug the "regular" Firefox. The problem is, that it automatically starts the non ESR Firefox and I would need something like an additional configuratation for ESR something like this:

  `{
            "type": "firefox-esr",
            "request": "launch",
            "reAttach": false,
            "name": "Launch Firefox ESR against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }`